# Rails routing: Changing the 'show' path for a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to change the `show` path to make it more SEO friendly. The code below throws an error when trying to go to `edit`

**routes.rb**

```
resources :posts, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :update, :edit]

match "posts/:id/:league_name/:post_description", to: 'posts#show', :as => :post, via: :get
```

**Error:**

```
No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show", :format=>nil, :id=>#<Post id: 1, title: "2 Pick Parlay", content: "<h1>Here you go</h1>\r\nStarting off the season right...", link: nil, created_at: "2016-07-31 21:45:40", updated_at: "2016-07-31 22:01:58", user_id: 2, league_id: 1, initial_status: nil, home_team: "", favorite: "", points: nil, visiting_team: "", event_datetime: "2016-09-09 00:30:00", spread_home: nil, spread_away: nil, total_points: nil, user_spread: nil, user_team_pick: nil, user_total_pick: nil, user_total_points: nil, user_line_source: nil, post_type: nil, event_id: 137, subscriber_only: false, release_at_gametime: false, is_parlay: true, flagged: false, weight: 1, post_description: "pick">}
```

When I take out the `form_for` on the `edit` page .. the page renders. So the problem must be in this code which is on the `edit` page

**Offending code in edit.haml.html:**

```
    = form_for(@post) do |f| 
    %h3
      Title for write up
    = f.text_field(:title, :class => "field span8")
    %br
    %br
    %h3
      Your analysis
    = f.text_area(:content, :class => "field span8", :rows => "5")
    <br/>
    = f.hidden_field(:league_id)  
    = f.hidden_field(:event_id) 
    = f.hidden_field(:home_team) 
    = f.hidden_field(:visiting_team)
    = f.hidden_field(:favorite) 
    = f.hidden_field(:points) 
    = f.hidden_field(:event_datetime)  
    %br
    %br  
    %h4
      - if @picks_tweet_string && @just_this_post_tweet_string
        - if @just_this_post_tweet_string.size > 130
          = link_to "Tweet these picks out now", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=#{@just_this_post_tweet_string}", confirm: "Click OK below. Then you may need to shorten the tweet to 140 characters. Most people remove the city name from the picks."
        - else  
          = link_to "Tweet these picks out now", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=#{@just_this_post_tweet_string}"
        %br  
        - if @picks_tweet_string.size > 130
          = link_to "I want to tweet my current full card", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=#{@picks_tweet_string}", confirm: "Click OK below. Then you may need to shorten the tweet to 140 characters. Most people remove the city name from the picks."
        - else  
          = link_to "I want to tweet my current full card", "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=#{@picks_tweet_string}"  
        %br
        %br  
    = f.submit "SUMBIT THIS WRITE-UP", class: 'btn-xlarge btn-block btn-primary' 
    %br
    %br
    = f.submit "No additional write-up", class: 'btn-xlarge btn-block btn-primary'
```

Any ideas what is wrong with that?

Comment: changing from from form_for to form_tag has worked. form_tag("/posts/#{@post.id}", method: :put) do

Comment: And finally.. I went with this form_for(@post, url: {action: "update"}) do |f| ... of course I updated my code block to include the f form helper. but the form_tag also works as I mention in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicated, but now that you've changed the show route, you've indirectly changed the edit route. Normally the edit route is based on the show route. Example:

```
show => "posts/:id"
edit => "posts/:id/edit"
```

Now you'll have to make an edit route that is:

```
"posts/:id/:league_name/:post_description"
```

In order to do that in your edit form:

```
= form_for([@post, @league, post_description: @post.post_description) do |f|
```

This is assuming that your `@league` object's `to_param` method returns `league_name`, otherwise you'd have to write:

```
= form_for([@post, league_name: @league.league_name, post_description: @post.post_description) do |f|
```

I'm sure you can see that this level of complexity may not be desired but this is how Rails works. Hence the adage: "Convention over configuration"

Comment: Thank you. I see. Interestingly enough... changing from from form_for to form_tag has worked. form_tag("/posts/#{@post.id}", method: :put) do

Comment: wondering if I should keep it how I have it with form_tag or use the example you do

Comment: also is the '[' in your form_for intentional?

Comment: yes it is because the first argument in `form_for` takes a symbol, an object, or an array. It uses this argument to determine the form submission path

Comment: Keep in mind you can also pass the URL to form_for though.